# ElasticSearch Finding the Total Length in a Cardinality Query

Tags: elasticsearch, cardinality, sense

I am using ElasticSearch and trying to find all the unique authors. And the total length of all the unique authors.

For example,

author: "Williams"
length: 100

author "Clint"
length : 200

author "Ron"
length: 100

author: "Williams"
length:200

I would be expecting Unique Authors 2 and the total length to be 300.

I have tried the following code ;

```
"size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "red_products": {
         "cardinality": {
            "field": "author"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "total": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "length"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But I get an error message saying Aggregator [red_products] of type [cardinality] cannot accept sub-aggregations.

And it I try it with the total length first and then the unique author it gives me the correct unique author but give me the total lengths of every book.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
"aggs": {
  "2": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "author",
      "size": 5,
      "order": {
        "1": "desc"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "1": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "length"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```